# 2 column table going from left to right WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

[image]

I have a 4 column table where 2 and 2 are same columns. I need the table to show informations in list going form left to right. 
So for example left "drink" column should show "A" and price show 1. Right "drink" column should show the next drink in the list, in this example it should show "B" and "1", not the same as the left column. And it should go on like that. The next item in the list should go down and left, etc.

Example

```
Drink        Price     Drink     Price

Karlovačko    15      Ožujsko     15

Graševina     20        etc.       x
```

Thank you for your help

c# code

```
namespace ElbaTrams_Kupac
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for AlkoholnaPica.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class AlkoholnaPica : Page
{
    public AlkoholnaPica()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<CjenikAlkohol> items = new List<CjenikAlkohol>();
        items.Add(new CjenikAlkohol() { Drink = "A", Price = 1 });
        items.Add(new CjenikAlkohol() { Drink = "B", Price = 2 });
        items.Add(new CjenikAlkohol() { Drink = "C", Price = 3 });
        alkoholCjenik.ItemsSource = items;
    }
    public class CjenikAlkohol
    {
        public string Drink { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }

    }
}
}
```

XAML code

```
d:DesignHeight="445" d:DesignWidth="400"
Title="AlkoholnaPica">

<Grid Background="#FF4AC1A7">
    <ListView Name="alkoholCjenik" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF042271" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Drink" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Drink}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Drink" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Drink}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That naming convention... I don't even know what to say

Comment: If you would point out how to improve myself, I will gladly do so. That's Why I'm on this site. This way you're not contributing to anything.

Comment: You should edit your question and add an example as a text, because currently it is not very clear.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to do this with a datagrid, but you could use two grids side by side and split the data items between them. Not elegant but might be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I edited it, and you can see the example now. 
@o_weisman Wouldn't that be needing 1 list for all, and then 2 more list for split data?

Comment: Yes it would. It's still probably simpler than trying to manage it with data templates or rolling out your own subclass of a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed advice by o_weisman in the comments. Split the list in 2 new lists. One list has even numbers of items, the other has uneven items. Later I will post the code, since it is still very simple and unorganized.